# QueryDSL / JPQL : how to build a join query?

Tags: jpa, jpql, querydsl

I've tried to read through the QueryDSL docs but I am still very confused.  I'm accustomed to writing a lot of SQL, but this is my first real crack at using QueryDSL w/ JPQL (JPA2).

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class Provider implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;


    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "provider_contact", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "provider_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @OrderColumn
    private Collection<Contact> contact;
}
```

where Contact is a simple entity with an `id` for a pk.

```
@Entity
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    /**
     * User first name
     */
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    /**
     * User last name
     */
    @NotNull
    private String lastName;
}
```

I'm trying to write a query which returns a `Contact` object given a specific Contact.id and Provider.id.  If the Contact object is not a part of the Provider's Contact collection, I'm looking for a null value.

I've tried the following:

```
public Contact getContact( long providerId, long contactId ){
    Predicate p = QProvider.provider.id.eq(providerId).and(QContact.contact.id.eq(contactId));
    JPQLQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);
    return query.from(QProvider.provider).innerJoin(QProvider.provider.contact).where(p).singleResult(QContact.contact);
}
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Undeclared path 'contact'. Add this path as a source to the query to be able to reference it.
    at com.mysema.query.types.ValidatingVisitor.visit(ValidatingVisitor.java:78)
    at com.mysema.query.types.ValidatingVisitor.visit(ValidatingVisitor.java:30)
    at com.mysema.query.types.PathImpl.accept(PathImpl.java:94)
```

I'm presuming it has something to do with the fact that my predicate references QContact.contact direction and not part of the QProvider.provider.contact object, but I'm really at a loss as to figure out how this should be done.

Am I even on the right track?  I'm not even sure my join is correct either.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This should work

```
public Contact getContact(long providerId, long contactId) {
    QProvider provider = QProvider.provider;
    QContact contact = QContact.contact;
    return new JPAQuery(em).from(provider)
        .innerJoin(provider.contact, contact)
        .where(provider.id.eq(providerId), contact.id.eq(contactId))
        .singleResult(contact);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks.  I didn't realize that aliases were so critical for QueryDSL.